# Adding field to Oracle SQL and SQL stops working

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following Oracle SQL that works.   All that I am trying to do is to add one field to the output and I cant get this SQL working:

Here is my information:

```
table name: access_log
col name: activity 
value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

Now here is my SQL that IS WORKING right now:

```
select   regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1') AS FILENAME,
COUNT   (regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1')) AS DOWNLOADS,
FROM access_log where id = 5339 and time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2014/02/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE ('2014/02/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1')
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

But I would like to change the SQL to also display the full values of "activity" all the way to the right but I cant add this field and keep the SQL working.. cna someone please help me..

Comment: Show please your query that does not work...

Comment: `count()` just is based on 'case' value.. And it cant be matched with the entire string, as there will be conflicts.. Though adding `MAX(activity)` to your `SELECT` will somehow get an activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
select   regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1') AS FILENAME,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY regexp_replace(activity, '^.*/(.*)/.*$', '\1')) AS DOWNLOADS,
         activity
FROM access_log
where id = 5339
  and time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2014/02/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE ('2014/02/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

We use `COUNT()` here as a window function approach.

Comment: Well, a bit off topic but any reason for `COUNT(1)`? Significance of 1? I would assume it to be a habit of old-developers ;-)

Comment: Lol, but I ain't tempted to reveal my age ;-)